# How do I make Bowser / Bowser Jr. throw hammers?

Tags: super-mario-maker

I played a level online where it looked like Bowser Jr. threw hammers.  I know Bowser does this in the original game.

I tried dragging a Hammer Bros. onto them, but this just replaces them with the Hammer Bros.

How do you make them throw hammers?

Side note: I know putting Bowser Jr. into the Koopa Clown Car makes him throw shells... and putting Bowser into the Koopa Clown Car makes him throw Bob-Ombs.

Comment: Just saw Bowser Jr. throwing hammers... and Cheep-Cheeps from the Koopa Clown Car in another level.  No idea how he's doing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZXZu3FKlxz4&t=5m37s), adding wings to Bowser Jr. causes him to throw hammers. Bowser himself doesn't seem to have a way to do this; you'll have to stack a source of hammers on top of him or something.

Comment: Hmm, I swear I've seen Bowser Jr. do it from within a Clown Car as well, but the level this was in had tons of enemies in Clown Cars, so theoretically I could have seen a Hammer Bros. doing it.  It was weird, because it was thrown in two directions at once like Bowser Jr. does with shells.

Comment: Was it a Bowser Jr. with wings in a clown car?

Comment: @Pyritie I don't believe so.

Comment: @Pyritie It appears that a Bowser Jr. with Wings will throw hammers if he's in a Clown Car as well, although not that often.  It may take time (or two hits) before he starts doing it, just like it does for fireballs.